# create image Hype Processing, processing.org

Tags: java, model-view-controller, processing

I am trying to create image using http://www.hypeframework.org/ and processing.org. I want to create the image and store in a folder then display it on the web using java spark. The following are the steps that I started with.

1. Create maven project using NetBeans
2. Added processing.org, spark libraries in maven
3. Downloaded hype processing jar added to my libraries

My question is how do I create image with then save it to the webapp folder? I am relatively new to hype and processing drawing shapes stuff. The following are my code that I put together:

Right now this cimg.setup() in the main spark controller throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#BC7A38,#996A37,#968063,#AB977C,#997949,#AE9162,#DFC597,#CAB790" error.

I searched google, but can't find any lead. Any help on how I should accomplish my task is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
//-- spark controller -
    public class Main {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
            get("/", new TemplateViewRoute() {
               @Override
                public ModelAndView handle(Request req, Response res) throws Exception {
                    HashMap model = new HashMap();
                   HypeProcessing cimg = new HypeProcessing();
                   cimg.setup();
                    model.put("template", "templates/form.vtl");
                    return new ModelAndView(model, "templates/layout.vtl");
                }
            }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
         }
   }


//--- HypeProcessing class ----
  public class HypeProcessing extends PApplet
  {
    HDrawablePool pool;
    HColorPool colors;

  @Override
  public void setup()
  {
    int h = 300;
    int w = 300;
    //size(w, h);
    //H.init(this).background(Integer.parseInt("#202020"));
    //smooth();

colors = new  HColorPool(Integer.parseInt("#BC7A38,#996A37,#968063,#AB977C,#997949,#AE9162,#DFC597,#CAB790"));

    pool = new HDrawablePool(121);
    pool.autoAddToStage()
    .add(new HShape("svg1.svg"))
    .add(new HShape("svg2.svg"))
    .add(new HShape("svg3.svg"))
    .add(new HShape("svg4.svg"))
    .add(new HShape("svg5.svg"))
    .add(new HShape("svg6.svg"))

    .layout(
        new HGridLayout()
        .startX(50)
        .startY(50)
        .spacing(50,50)
        .cols(11)
    )

            .onCreate(
        new HCallback() {

                            @Override
            public void run(Object obj) {
                HShape d = (HShape) obj;
                d
                    .enableStyle(false)
                    .strokeJoin(ROUND)
                    .strokeCap(ROUND)
                    .strokeWeight(1)
                    .stroke(Integer.parseInt("#000000"))
                    // .anchorAt(H.CENTER)
                    .rotate( (int)random(4) * 90 )
                    .size( 50 + ( (int)random(4) * 50 ) ) // 50, 100, 150, 200
                ;
                d.randomColors(colors.fillOnly());
            }
        }
    )
    .requestAll();
saveImage(w,h); 
noLoop();
// ...
  }

  @Override
  public void draw()
  {
    //rect(10, 10, 80, 80);
      H.drawStage();
    // ...
  }

  public void saveImage(int width, int height)
  {
      //Helper c = new Helper();
      String p = "webapp/images/";
      String fn = p+"image_"+Helper.generateRandomNumber();
      PGraphics img = createGraphics(width, height);
      img.beginDraw();
      boolean use3D = false;
      float alpha = 1;
      H.stage().paintAll(img, use3D, alpha);
      img.endDraw();
      img.save(fn);
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing uses a custom `color` type. You can use web notation like `#ff00ff`, and under the hood Processing stores that as an integer, so you can even do things like:

```
int c = #ff00ff;
```

However, Java functions like `Integer.parseInt()` have no idea how to handle web notation. Java has no way of mapping a String like `"#ff00ff"` to an `int` value. This is why you're getting your error.

Even if Java did know how to map web notation to an `int` value, you're passing in multiple values within a single `String`, which doesn't make a ton of sense.

But the point is, you can only use web notation if you're using the Processing editor. If you're writing this in something other than the Processing editor, you'll have to use the `color()` function.

```
HColorPool(color(0, 255, 0), color(255, 0, 255), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks!, that fixed error. But, now i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hype.HShape.shape(Unknown Source)
 at hype.HShape.<init>(Unknown Source).  I am not sure if I am setting hype correctly using pojo. Unknown sources--probably i didn't initialize the object, but don't how.  I am not using processing IDE. Any example that creates a pojo hype processing object using processing to store an image to file will put me on the right track.

Comment: Can you post your updated code, preferably as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Include the full text of the stack trace as well. You might be better off asking a new question. "Unknown source" just means that the library you're using doesn't include source code- that's not an error message.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the first answer and ask new question with error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

There is java code for the translation:-

java.awt.Color.decode("ff00ff").getRGB();

Its a bit obscure is what I use in JRubyArt